# How can I create an Array from an UnsafeBufferPointer without copying?

Tags: arrays, swift, memory, buffer, swift2

I'm in a tricky situation where I have a very large memory represented by an `UnsafeBufferPointer`, and I need to represent it as an `Array`. Now, the Swift standard library offers an initializer that *copies* elements from any given sequence, however it offers no way to directly provide the underlying storage.

Is there any way I can 'cast' an `UnsafeBufferPointer` to an `Array` while avoiding copying?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct UnsafeBufferPointer<Element> { ... }
```

> A non-owning pointer to buffer of Elements stored contiguously in
>   memory, presenting a Collection interface to the underlying elements.

The answer is no, it is impossible.

```
init(start: UnsafePointer<Element>, count: Int)
```

> Construct an UnsafePointer over the count contiguous Element instances
>   beginning at start.

The constructor doesn't copy anything anywhere. The constructor doesn't create any memory allocation

Comment: I want to create an `Array` out of an `UnsafeBufferPointer`. I already know how `UnsafeBufferPointer` works.

Comment: it is because the UnsafeBufferPointer is presenting collection interface to other underlying elements. how did you create it? you have to have the underlying elements in you possession ....

Comment: i did. still the answer is the same. you are not able to create an Array over some memory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95837/discussion-between-user3441734-and-vatsal-manot).